# ValueError: URLs are not writeable (np.savetext)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am doing text based clustering of various news articles using k-means clustering. I have cleaned the data of any stopwords, punctuations, stemmed etc. The clustering part is successful. 
The problem I am facing is in the part where I want to write the matrix as a text file.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_clean_sentences)   
np.savetxt('E://csr.txt', X, delimiter=" ")
```

train_clean_sentences is a list of sentences I have pre-processed and cleaned, while X is a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

This code returns an error saying:

> np.savetxt('E://csr.txt', X, delimiter=" ") Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in 
>       np.savetxt('E://csr.txt', X, delimiter=" ")
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1308,
>   in savetxt
>       fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'wt', encoding=encoding)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib_datasource.py", line
>   260, in open
>       return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib_datasource.py", line
>   605, in open
>       raise ValueError("URLs are not writeable")
>
> ValueError: URLs are not writeable

I have made it sure that the text to be converted does not contain any URLs as the punctuation has been removed.

The output text file should be something like this:
[image: Output txt file]

where each row will show the cluster distance of that centroid from other centroids in the cluster.

Comment: Why do you have to forward slashes in your path? Don't you want a double backward slash? Or use `os.path.join('E:', 'csr.txt')` and avoid those issues.

Comment: Try `'E:\\csr.txt'` or `r'E:\csr.txt'`.

Comment: Writing a `csr_matrix` with `savetxt` isn't going to work.  You'll have to convert it to a dense 2d array, e.g. `X.toarray()`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes you are correct, after resolving the above state problem I faced this issue but converting it to an array using toarray() gave me a 2.7GB output file which I am unable to open due to its size. I have a sample file as the solution to this and it should not be more than 15MB. Can you guess what am I missing?

Comment: What's the shape?

Comment: @hpaulj shape is 3000x36887

Comment: 3000 * 36887 * 25 = 27G - 25 bytes per element.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks.. I don't know where am I going wrong... I should be not be getting a matrix of this shape, the number of rows at 3000 is correct though... will have to revesit my code for the nth time now... anyways thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

np.savetxt('E://csr.txt', X, delimiter=" ") ×

np.savetxt('E:/csr.txt', X, delimiter=" ") √

Answer (score 0):

> `np.savetxt('E:/csr.txt', X.toarray(), delimiter=" ")`

Use a double slash `//` as parameters seems to be incorrectly processed on `savetxt`, i certainly do not know why this happend and if it is an issue with [this module source (npyio.py#L1320-L1565)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1320-L1565), instead to backslash `\` symbol that have many different uses such as break line `\n`, quotes `\'`, tab character `\t` and others; Using [`toarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) converts to a efficient representation of a sparse matrix that `sklearn` uses in ordinary readable dense **ndarray** representation, to deal with his large output file you could use:

```py
def read(file, size=2764): # read in chunks 2.7GB=2,764.8MB
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        while chunk := f.read(chunk_size):
            yield chunk
```